# Parsing HTML in silverlight

Tags: c#, html-parsing, silverlight-5.0

I am working on one display of my project. On that display i have one column in which data is coming from database table in the form of HTML, i have to parse that HTML. I have tried it using RadHtmlPlaceholder and binding its HtmlSource property with view model property which is holding the HTML coming from database table. but in my company we can't use third party controls.. also that RadHtmlPlaceholder do not have the option to change the font style..so help me out to parse the HTML in silverlight

Comment: Show your code what you have tried.

Comment: <DataTemplate>
<telerik:RadHtmlPlaceholder x:Name="RadHtmlPlaceholder1" HtmlSource="{Binding OtherMsg}" />
</DataTemplate>